# MySQL Spatial Object for multiple polygons that may or may not be connected

Tags: mysql, spatial

I have a set of of polygons. Sometimes they are completely disconnected (like separate patches). Other times, two sides of two polygons may touch each other (when the polygons are adjacent like on a chess board). The polygons never cross each other. In other words, their intersection is always empty.

I need to check if a point is contained in any one of those polygons. Is there a way I can build a single geometry using these polygons and check if the point is in it?

Currently I'm building a long `WHERE` close with `OR` conditions and do something like the below:

```
st_contains(st_GeomFromText('POLYGON(("+polygon+"))'), st_GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT()')))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Dup of stackexchange question?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195673/should-i-join-all-of-my-polygons-to-make-a-single-polygon-for-point-in-polygon-s